# Using jQuery $.ajax to post json encoded data to a php script: success event is doing nothing

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, mysqli

I am making an ajax call using jquery to post data as json to a php file, however nothing is happening on `success`. My code is below :

### AJAX section

```
$.ajax({
    url:"myData.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    method:"POST",
    data:'country',                      
    success:function(j){
        var $country = $("#country");
        $.each(j, function () {   
            $country.append($('<option></option>').attr("value", this.country_id).text(this.country_name));
        });
    }
});
```

### PHP section

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['country'])){
    $conn=new MySQLi("localhost","root","","newdb");
    $myQuery="select * from country";

    $result=$conn->query($myQuery);

    while($country=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo json_encode($country);
    }
}
```

### HTML section

```
<label >country:</label>
<select class="form-control"  id="country" >
    <option>---select---</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you please check the network traffic in the developer tools of your browser?

Comment: what data you want to send to server?

Comment: {"country_id":"5","country_name":"pakistan"}{"country_id":"6","country_name":"india"}{"country_id":"7","country_name":"america"}{"country_id":"8","country_name":"Bnagladesh"}

this is the response from server

Comment: I have reworded the question to be less wordy, however if the context was lost, please modify the title so that it is short, and clearly describes the problem.

Comment: thanks @KraangPrime for ur help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to collect all countries in array then echo json.

```
$countries = [];
if(isset($_REQUEST['country'])){
    $conn=new MySQLi("localhost","root","","newdb");
    $myQuery="select * from country";

    $result=$conn->query($myQuery);

    while($country=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        $countries[] = $country;
    }
     echo json_encode($countries);
}
```

Also in js send country as parameter.

```
...
method:"POST",
data: {country : true},
...
```

Comment: thankew soo much @anwer bro it really work. i apericiate ur help thnx alot :)